# Jest Module Mock with ECMAScript Modules

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, es6-modules, ecmascript-2017

Using the documentation (https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) as a guide, I have written the following:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "watch-test": "jest ./test --verbose --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ethers": "^5.6.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {}
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

`test/test.js`:

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals';
import {ethers} from 'ethers';

jest.mock('ethers', () => ({ethers: 'Hello, world!'}));
console.log(ethers);
```

Use the following to execute the test: `npm i && NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npm run watch-test;`. The output is `console.log {Signer: [Getter],Wallet: [Getter],...` and so on but I wish it said something like `console.log "Hello, world!"`.

It appears that the `ethers` module (or the `ethers` object in the module?) is not getting mocked at all. I tried moving the `jest.mock` call above the `import` (which shouldn't be necessary because of jest hoisting), but that didn't help anything.

How do I mock the `ethers` module using jest when using ECMAScript modules configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although hoisting is done in common JS, it is not done using ECMAScript Modules, so instead of `import`ing mocked modules, you must use dynamic import to import them after the mocking.

`test/test.js`:

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals';
jest.mock('ethers', () => ({ethers: 'Hello, world!'}));
const {ethers} = await import('ethers');

test('do it', ()=> {
    expect(ethers).toEqual("Hello, world!");
});
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "watch-test": "jest ./test --verbose --watch"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "ethers": "^5.6.9"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "jest": "^28.1.3"
    },
    "jest": {
        "verbose": true,
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/test/**/*.?(c)js"
        ],
        "transform" : {}
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```

(`"testMatch": "test/**"` doesn't work, you must prefix with `<rootDir>` or `**`; I'm not sure why.)

And invoked as stated in the question.

This conversation got me on the right track: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/13135